# Unsupported Exception in jsf 2.0 + springwebflow 2.0

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, jboss7.x, spring-webflow

I started to create a project using the following technologies

```
JSF 2.0 
Springwebflow 2.0
Primefaces 2.2.1
Richfaces 3.3
Appserver : JBOSS-AS-7.1.1 Final
```

My application got deployed successfully, but when i am trying to run it.. i am getting the following exception,

> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'startPage' of flow 'main'
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException:
>   Exception thrown in state 'startPage' of flow 'main'
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:569)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
>     org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
>     org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>     javax.faces.context.ExternalContext.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContext.java:1228)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:206)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>     org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:91)
>     org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
>     org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
>     org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:88)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:282)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:241)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:219)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
>     org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
>     org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
>     org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>     org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

Any Idea what the cause is ?

```
my faces-config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

</faces-config>

my web.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- 
        JSF 2 IMPLEMENTATION
    -->
    <!-- Use JSF view templates saved as *.xhtml, for use with Facelets -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Enables special Facelets debug output during development -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize, *not* used at runtime -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 
        SPRING MVC
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>
            javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
        </param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>

my webflow-config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Executes flows: the central entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="1" />
        <webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
            <webflow:always-redirect-on-pause value="true"/>
        </webflow:flow-execution-attributes>
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />

        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
    <faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />

    <!-- Installs a listener to apply Spring Security authorities -->
    <bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener" />


</beans>
```

Comment: How have you configured jsf2.0 with jboss 7.1.1?

Comment: Can you also post your applicationContext, If you are starting a new project I can suggest you to look at code generated by Springfuse to make things easier. Here is the [link](http://www.springfuse.com/)

Comment: yes Mukul, i configured.

Comment: I don't do SWF, but I know that it comes with a custom `FacesContext` implementation, the `FlowFacesContext`. This exception suggests that it is not properly referencing/maintaining the `ExternalContext`. Try upgrading to the latest SWF version.

Comment: i upgraded my SWF to 2.3, but still i am getting the same exception.

Comment: its very urgent, can any one plz help me out on this issue as soon as possible.  or tell me is it possible to use swf2.3+primefaces2.2.1+jsf 2.0, if so plz provide me one sample example including configurations. i spent lot of time on this, i hope this stack overflow will help me.

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your jsf to 2.2.15, same problem i was getting in my project !